# Link2SD - Lost first SD partition

Tags: partitions, link2sd

I've been running Link2SD on a year or so with no issues. I use an 16GB SD card with a 1GB second partition. I have most of my stuff linked to SD, but a few apps I just left on the first SD card partition. Within the past week or so, it seems I've lost my first partition. When I go to Storage Info in Link2SD, it shows the same stats for /mnt/sdcard and /data/sdext2. All the apps that were on my first partition are missing, along with all my music, pictures, and application data. File explorers on the phone just show the stuff from the second partition, as well.

When I connect via usb to a pc I can see all the files and folders on the first partition, so it is there and I can get to them via the phone's usb connection.

Is this a link2sd isssue or a "funny" with mounting the SD's first partition?

Any help gratefully accepted.